# Finding the vertex of a quadratic equation with two unkowns

Tags: inequality, quadratics

First of all, let me state the problem and my rationale:

**Show the range of values of $k$ for which $x^2-kx+2k+1=0$ has distinct real roots**

*Premise I:* The discriminant is: $b^2 - 4ac$*

*Premise II: $ Discriminant > 0$, otherwise if $discriminant=0$ it has only one root and if $ discriminant < 0$ then it's not in the real domain.*

Then:

1. $b^2 - 4ac > 0$
2. $(-k)^2 -4(1 * 2k +1)$
3. $k^2 - 8k - 4 > 0 $
4. $(k-4)^2 - 4^2 - 4 > 0$ `Completing the squares`
5. $(k-4)^2 - 20 > 0$
6. $(k-4)^2 > 20$

At this point I can tell that this is zero if $ (k - 4)^2 = 20 $

Hence, we can deduce:

$|k-4| >\sqrt{20}$

This tell us that either $k-4 > \sqrt{20}$ or that $-(k-4) > \sqrt{20}$

Therefore, the range is: 
$\{k: k < 4- 2\sqrt{5}\} \cup \{k: k > 4 +2\sqrt{5}\} $

because that's when $k^2 -8k-4 > 0$

Great.

**Now to the question:**

Since $a > 0$ this parabola will have a minimum. Where's the vertex of this equation?

Getting the vertex form $a(x -h) + k$ on step 5 I get the coordinates $(-4,-20)$. But that can't be since $(k-4)^2>20$ so that it can have two distinct roots. Besides, getting $(-4,-20)$ yields a strangely shaped parabola that grows towards the northeast side of my Cartesian plan.

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
Edit-1: Replacing "k" by "discriminant" on Premise II.
```

Comment: Your premise II is false. The sign of the _discriminant_ determines the number of real solutions, but that’s not the same as the sign of $k$: you’ve clearly shown that when $k=0$ there are _no_ real roots, and similarly that there are negative values of $k$ for which the equation does have real roots.

Comment: The vertex of a parabola has $x=\frac{-b}{2a}$

Comment: I think in premise II you meant to write $b^2-4ac$ instead of $k.$ That is, it is the sign of the discriminant (not of some other parameter in the formula) that tells you when there are two roots, one root, or no roots.

Comment: The parabola has a vertex regardless of the number of its real roots, and it will depend on $k$. It’s a bit hard to follow what you’re doing, but it looks like you’ve found the vertex of the parabola $(k-4)^2=20$ instead of the original parabola.

Comment: Sorry! You're totally right... I totally meant the discriminant on Premise II. I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If construct a Cartesian plane in which you label one axis $k$ and the other axis $y,$ then the graph of the equation $y = k^2−8k−4$ is a parabola with vertex
$(-4,-20),$ which is what you find when you apply the vertex form
$y = a(k-h)^2 + L$ to the equation $y = k^2−8k−4.$

But I think the parabola whose vertex you are supposed to find is the graph of
$$y = x^2−kx+2k+1$$
in a conventional Cartesian plane where the axes are labeled $x$ (not $k$) and $y.$
So you should apply the vertex form to $x^2−kx+2k+1$ (viewed as a quadratic over $x,$ where $k$ is some as-yet-unspecified constant) rather than to $k^2−8k−4$ (viewed as a quadratic over $k$).

Comment: You actually made me realise two things: 1: It's totally fine to have vertex at $(-4,-20)$ for my $k^2 -8k -4$ expression. And 2: I can find the vertex for $ y = x^2 -kx +2k + 1$ with distinct roots as long as $\{k: k < 4- 2\sqrt{5}\} \cup \{k: k > 4 +2\sqrt{5}\} $ . My parabola will change it's shape depending on the values assigned to $k$ and $x$. The problem is "which range to get distinct roots" and not "what are those roots" as it will change according to the variables. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write your function in the form
$$f(x)=\left(x-\frac{k}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{k^2}{4}-2k-1\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Note: I will convert to LaTex/MathJax at a later time when I am able to...

[image]

Note I had to alter the value $2*\sqrt{5}+4$ to be $-0.47124$ instead of $-0.47123$ and the value $2*sqrt{5}+4$ to $8.47214$ instead of the value   $8.47213$ for the answer to work. I can't tell why the original values don't work!